# converting date from one time zone to other time zone in java

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I wanted to convert a date from one time zone to another, using SimpleDateFormat class in java. But somehow it is generating different results which are suppose to be in the same TimeZone.

Here is a test case, and its generating one result as IST and other one as GMT. i think it should be generating only GMT's for both cases.

```
public class TestOneCoreJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {// Asia/Calcutta
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
        System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(formatter.parse("26-Nov-10 03:31:20 PM +0530"),"Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Dublin", false));
        System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(formatter.parse("02-Oct-10 10:00:00 AM +0530"),"Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Dublin", false));
        //------Output--
        //26-Nov-10 GMT
        //02-Oct-10 IST
    }

    public static String getDateStringToShow(Date date,
            String sourceTimeZoneId, String targetTimeZoneId, boolean includeTime) {
        String result = null;

        // System.out.println("CHANGING TIMEZONE:1 "+UnitedLexConstants.SIMPLE_FORMAT.format(date));
        String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a").format(date);

        SimpleDateFormat sourceTimeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
        sourceTimeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(sourceTimeZoneId));

        date1 += " " + sourceTimeZoneFormat.format(date);

        // Changed from 'Z' to 'z' to show IST etc, in place of +5:30 etc.
        SimpleDateFormat targetTimeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a z");
        targetTimeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(targetTimeZoneId));

        SimpleDateFormat timeZoneDayFormat = null;
        if (includeTime) {
            timeZoneDayFormat = targetTimeZoneFormat;
        } else {
            timeZoneDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy z");
        }
        timeZoneDayFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(targetTimeZoneId));
        try {
            result = timeZoneDayFormat.format(targetTimeZoneFormat.parse(date1));
            // System.out.println("CHANGING TIMEZONE:3 "+result);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
ZonedDateTime                         // Represent a date and time-of-day in a specific time zone.
.now(                                 // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )   // Specify time zone using proper name in `Continent/Region` format. Never use 3-4 letter pseudo-zone such as IST or PST or EST.
)                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameInstant(                 // Adjust from one time zone to another. Same point on the timeline, same moment, but different wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )       
)                                     // Returns a new fresh `ZonedDateTime` object rather than altering/“mutating” the original, per immutable objects pattern.
.toString()                           // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, extended to append name of zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-09-18T21:47:32.035960+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

For UTC, call [`ZonedDateTime::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant()).

## Avoid 3-Letter Time Zone Codes

Avoid those three-letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. For example, your use of "IST" may mean India Standard Time, Irish Standard Time, and maybe others.

Use proper [time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). The definition of time zones and their names change frequently, so keep your source up-to-date. For example the old "Asia/Calcutta" is now "Asia/Kolkata". And not just names; governments are notorious for changing the rules/behavior of a time zone, occasionally at the last minute.

## Avoid j.u.Date

Avoid using the bundled java.util.Date and Calendar classes. They are notoriously troublesome and will be supplanted in Java 8 by the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (which was inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)).

## java.time

### `Instant`

Learn to think and work in UTC rather than your own parochial time zone. Logging, data-exchange, and data-storage should usually be done in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-09-18T20:48:43.354953Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

Adjust into a time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time. Apply a `ZoneId` (time zone) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = instant.atZone( zMontreal ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

We can adjust again, using either the `Instant` or the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdtMontreal.withZoneSameInstant​( zKolkata ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Calling `toString` on any of these classes produce text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) class. The `ZonedDateTime` class extends the standard wisely by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

When exchanging date-time values as text, always use ISO 8601 formats. Do not use custom formats or localized formats as seen in your Question.

The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default for both parsing and generating strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z" ) ;
```

Using standard formats avoids all that messy string manipulation seen in the Question.

### Adjust to UTC

You can always take a `ZonedDateTime` back to UTC by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdtKolkata.toInstant() ;
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

To represent your date-time value in other formats, [search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20Java%20DateTimeFormatter&t=osx&ia=web) class. You will find many examples and discussions.

---

UPDATE: The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, and advises migration to the *java.time* classes. I am leaving this section intact as history.

## Joda-Time

Beware of java.util.Date objects that seem like they have a time zone but in fact do not. In Joda-Time, a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) does indeed know its assigned time zone. Generally should specify a desired time zone. Otherwise, the JVM's default time zone will be assigned.

Joda-Time uses mainly immutable objects. Rather than modify an instance, a new fresh instance is created. When calling methods such as [`toDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toDateTime%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29), a new fresh DateTime instance is returned leaving the original object intact and unchanged.

```java
//DateTime now = new DateTime(); // Default time zone automatically assigned.

// Convert a java.util.Date to Joda-Time.
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateTime now = new DateTime( date );  // Default time zone automatically assigned.

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime nowIndia = now.toDateTime( timeZone );

// For UTC/GMT, use built-in constant.
DateTime nowUtcGmt = nowIndia.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Convert from Joda-Time to java.util.Date.
java.util.Date date2 = nowIndia.toDate();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "nowIndia: " + nowIndia );
System.out.println( "nowUtcGmt: " + nowUtcGmt );
System.out.println( "date2: " + date2 );
```

When run…

```
date: Sat Jan 25 16:52:28 PST 2014
now: 2014-01-25T16:52:28.003-08:00
nowIndia: 2014-01-26T06:22:28.003+05:30
nowUtcGmt: 2014-01-26T00:52:28.003Z
date2: Sat Jan 25 16:52:28 PST 2014
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Timezone issues in Google API. I came across such kind of issues.

Look at this piece of code of yours:-

```
 System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(formatter.parse("26-Nov-10 03:31:20 PM 
 +0530"),"Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Dublin", false));
 System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(formatter.parse("02-Nov-10 10:00:00 AM 
 +0530"),"Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Dublin", false));
```

*If i give above as input it will run fine the way we want to.*

---

If you still want to go with this way then you have to perform calculation according to your need.

Like adjusting the time Mathematically and things similar to it.

---

Or a **Simple fix** for your case will be something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat d =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
d.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Dublin"));
Date firsttime = d.parse("2013-12-19T03:31:20");
Date seondtime = d.parse("2013-12-19T10:00:00");

System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(firsttime,"Asia/Calcutta",
"Europe/Dublin", false));
System.out.println(getDateStringToShow(seondtime,"Asia/Calcutta", 
"Europe/Dublin", false));
```

---

My suggestion will be to refer [JODA API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) . More preferrable over Old School Date.